# Need someone who has Mac OS X Mountain Lion? Udp Probes

Tags: macos, udp, osx-lion, dtrace

If you have Mac OS X Mountain Lion could you write " sudo dtrace  -ln udp:::  " to your Terminal screen and copy the results for me?

I need to learn are UDP probes available for new OS .

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the response from my computer.

```
   ID   PROVIDER            MODULE                          FUNCTION NAME
dtrace: failed to match udp:::: No probe matches description
```